# .Net DataGridView "Index 0 does not have a value."

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I am having trouble with a DataGridView.
I have a collection of 3 Items bound to the grid, when trying to delete one of the items and reload the grid.

If have code of

```
If (dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
     'Show dialog with grid on it
End If
```

On the opened dialog, I delete an item from the grid (which should in turn, delete the item from the collection, and re-load the grid), and it returns to the "If (dlg.show..." line, with the error of

"A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Index 2 does not have a value. "

(I have break into debugger set on for common language runtime errors)

I can understand this error if i were trying to access any cells, row or columns, but im not, and then I would expect the exception to stop on the line of code that is trying to access this grid data, not the "If (dlg.ShowDialog()... " line

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have discovered that if you add in

```
DataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
DataGridView.Refresh()
```

before resetting the grid to the collection (with the deleted item removed)

```
DataGridView.DataSource = MyCollection
```

It works like a charm.
Still interested as to why you have to do this.

Comment: Refresh shouldn't be needed and potentially will slow down things.

Comment: If the datasource list is modified, the datagrid will loose control. Records can be offered to the datagrid as an array using List.ToArray(). Items in the array are not copies. By using an array they are presented in a structure not affected if the list is cleared or updated.

Comment: Wow, fantastic...  thanks for the simple solution.  I modified it slightly out of concern I was going to lose my customizations - `DataGridView.DataSource = typeOf(myObjectClass);` (this is C#) but conceptually this was the solution -- to disconnect the grid from my data source before reconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that since you are showing a modal dialog, the error that is thrown is shown there. Have you tried to set a break point in the line of code that actually does the deleting from the grid/collection to see if the error is coming from that?

Comment: Ive set a breakpoint and gone thru the deleting methods, it goes through the removing the item from the collection and re-binding the datasource on the grid without a problem. the point where the error throws is on the "End Sub" of the method that handles the menu item click event (ctxMenuDelete.Click), from here it returns to the "If (dlg.ShowDialog()..." on the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a .Net bug, i created a test program, it still fails, but i got a workaround by adding Null check and items count before data source binding:

```
If MyCollection IsNot Nothing AndAlso MyCollection.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView.DataSource = MyCollection
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This error mean the DataSource have got empty or null before you set it to null.

For Example: This will jump out the same your exception

```
DataGridView.DataSource = Mylist; 
Mylist.clear();
DataGridView.DataSource = null;
updateMyList();
DataGridView.DataSource = MyList;
```

In my case, it will jump out Exception if anything in your code (Thread/Timer or any function) try to get data row/colum from DataGrid (such as select all row..) by the time MyList got clearing/Empty. To fix it, these is re-code worked with me:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = Mylist; 
DataGridView.DataSource = null; // Set null frist, take it seperate with data
Mylist.clear();                 // clear data 
updateMyList();                   // update data...
DataGridView.DataSource = MyList; // update table, free error
```

Good Luck